# JQuery mobile multiple panels not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'am developing an web application with jQuery mobile and I've on my index.php 3 different pages (div data-role="page"). For that 3 pages I want to have a panel in each one. 
That's what I've tried:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="contentPrincipal">

    <?php
        if($view != 'admobile'){
    ?>

    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="open-panel" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
        <h1 id="title"></h1>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var title = $("title").text();
            $("#title").text(title);
        </script>
    </div>



    <?php
        }
    ?>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <?php

        if ($option == "com_telem_articles" || ($option == "com_ads" && $view == "listmobile")){ // Listagens das notícias, usados e passatempos

            /*$articleID = JRequest::getCmd('article');
            if ($articleID){
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                usadosReturn(<?php echo $articleID; ?>);
            </script>
        <?php
            }*/
        ?>
            <div data-test-role="flip"  data-test-loop="false" data-test-show-pager="false">
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>

        <?php
        } else { //Detalhe de um usado
            $articleID = JRequest::getCmd('id');
            $ecode = JRequest::getCmd('ecode'); //Se o utilizador enviar um email, vai ser recebido aqui o código 1 ou 0 (enviado ou erro a enviar)     

        ?>


            <div id="used" data-article-id="<?php echo $articleID;?>">

                <div id="form_warning_top">
                    <div id="form_warning">
                        <div class="box">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Não forneça dados pessoais completos ou a morada completa.</li>
                                <li>Se ainda não conheceu o anunciante pessoalmente, tenha em conta a regra de confiança limitada.</li>
                                <li>Lembre-se de conhecer o anunciante em pessoa</li>
                                <li>Verifique outras regras de segurança</li>
                            </ul>
                            <button class="dontshow">Não voltar a mostrar esta mensagem.</button>
                            <a title="Close" class="form_warning_close" href="javascript:;"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php if ($ecode == 1) { //Email enviado?>

                    <div id="system-message-container">
                        <div id="system-message">
                            <div class="alert alert-message">
                                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                                <h4 class="alert-heading">Mensagem</h4>
                            <div>
                            <p>Email Enviado com Sucesso</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php } else if ($ecode == 2) { //Erro ao enviar email?>

                    <div id="system-message-container">
                        <div id="system-message">
                            <div class="alert alert-notice">
                                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                                <h4 class="alert-heading">Aviso</h4>
                            <div>
                            <p>Ocorreu um Problema ao Enviar Email.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php } ?>

                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            <!</div>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="contentDetails">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="open-panel" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
        <h1 id="title"></h1>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var title = $("title").text();
            $("#title").text(title);
        </script>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div data-test-role="flip_aux"  data-test-loop="false" data-test-show-pager="false"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="usedContentDetails">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="open-panel" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
        <h1 id="title"></h1>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var title = $("title").text();
            $("#title").text(title);
        </script>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" id="used_content" class="ui-content">

        <iframe id="usadosIframe" style="border:0;" src=""></iframe>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){   
    $('<div>').attr({
        'id':'mypanel',
        'data-role':'panel'
    }).appendTo($(this));

    $("#mypanel").html('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li><a href="/telemoveis_j3/index.php" rel="external">&Uacute;ltimas not&iacute;cias</a></li><li><a href="/telemoveis_j3/index.php?option=com_ads&view=listmobile&Itemid=118" rel="external">Usados</a></li><li><a href="/telemoveis_j3/index.php?option=com_telem_articles&view=categorymobile&id=40&Itemid=119" rel="external">Passatempos</a></li></ul>');

    $(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){   
        $.mobile.activePage.find('#mypanel').panel("open");      
    });    
});
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Start by eliminating duplicate ID attributes from your markup; each ID should be unique.

Comment: Which id are you talking about ? <a id="open-panel"> ?

Comment: #title is duplicated several times. See my answer below. I can provide a working demo if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the panel to be added to only one page then target that page only and instead of using 'pagebeforecreate' use 'pagebeforeshow', as follows:

Then enhance the parent of the panel and lastly trigger a click event on the panel opener.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#contentPrincipal', function(){ 
    $('<div>').attr({
        'id':'mypanel',
        'data-role':'panel'
    }).appendTo($(this));

    $("#mypanel").html('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li><a href="/telemoveis_j3/index.php" rel="external">&Uacute;ltimas not&iacute;cias</a></li><li><a href="/telemoveis_j3/index.php?option=com_ads&view=listmobile&Itemid=118" rel="external">Usados</a></li><li><a href="/telemoveis_j3/index.php?option=com_telem_articles&view=categorymobile&id=40&Itemid=119" rel="external">Passatempos</a></li></ul>').parent().enhanceWithin();

    $(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){   
        $('#mypanel').panel("open");      
    });
    $('#open-panel').click();    
});
```

**EDIT**
The code has been updated to add a panel opener button to each page. Since the content in all the panels would have been the same it make sense to create one panel only.

NOTE: Since you already have #open-panel, you do not need to create buttons in each page.

Comment: Then to avoid generating invalid HTML by creating duplicate IDs let's use classes selectors for the panel and the panel opener buttons. Agree? I'll edit my answer shortly. Or better still, if the panels contain the same content, why not have one panel?

Comment: and how can I change page and keep the panel with only one ?

Comment: Two ways: 1. have an icon or a button to pen the panel in a fixed header. 2. have a button in each page to pen the panel. How do you currently move from page to page?

Comment: Ok with the code above, you should see an 'Open Panel' button at the bottom of each page. Let me know if there's a problem.

Comment: Nice answer. user3042700 if you have more questions you should open a new one,  user3558931 gave you a solution for this one. Plus don't forget to accept this answer if it's a working one.